Getting a p-value of 0 when comparing two samples using bootstrapping
I am comparing two samples using a bootstrap method I found online (I have not checked the boot package yet). The script seems like it should work but for some reason, I am getting a p-value=0 which means that all the differences of means in the bootstrap are lower than the observed difference. It doesn't matter what dataset I use it seems to keep giving me the same results. Is there something I am missing in the code?
set.seed(123)

dataset1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2)
dataset2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 15, sd = 2)

combined_df <- data.frame(
 value = c(dataset1, dataset2),
 group = factor(c(rep("Group1", length(dataset1)), rep("Group2", length(dataset2))))
)

# Number of observations
n <- length(combined_df$value)
# Number of bootstrap iterations
B <- 10000

variable <- combined_df$value
boots <- matrix(sample(variable, size=n*B, replace=TRUE), nrow=n, ncol=B)

bootstat1 <- numeric(B)  # for mean differences
bootstat2 <- numeric(B)  # for median differences

# Calculate observed differences
observed_means_diff <- abs(mean(dataset1) - mean(dataset2))
observed_medians_diff <- abs(median(dataset1) - median(dataset2))

for (i in 1:B) {
 boot_sample <- boots[, i]
 bootstat1[i] <- abs(mean(boot_sample[1:100]) - mean(boot_sample[101:200]))
 bootstat2[i] <- abs(median(boot_sample[1:100]) - median(boot_sample[101:200]))
}

# Calculate p-values
p_value_mean <- mean(bootstat1 >= observed_means_diff)
p_value_median <- mean(bootstat2 >= observed_medians_diff)


Thank you for all the help

dataset1 and dataset2 are so different from each other that it is very, very unlikely that the difference in mean or median of two independent samples from the combined datasets will exceed the differences between the two datasets. Try running it again with dataset2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 11, sd = 2).

There doesn't appear to be any problems with the code. As @jblood94 pointed out, you are using groups with two very different means: an absolute difference in mean of 5 with a standard deviation of only 2 -- very lille overlap. This the outcome you would expect given the setup. If you need help better understanding how bootstrapping works and what to expect when using that method, you should instead ask for help at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on-topic.

Thanks for the replies. Even if I change the mean of dataset2 to 11 I will get a mean value of 0. That is why I thought maybe there was something wrong with some calculation.

I get p_value_mean = 0.0265 and p_value_median = 0.1675 if I make only that one change to the code you posted.

Ok now it changed. That ws odd because when I tried it first time I got a mean of 0 and a median very low median.
I will check Cross Validated because I am having the same problem with a dataset that should be significantly different but I still get 0 for the p value

Good! If two datasets are very different, you should expect a p-value of 0 (or very close to 0).
